# How to get VS Code to scroll to source line when breakpoint hit

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

When VS Code encounters a breakpoint that pauses the program, I expect the source file to be opened and the exact line of execution scrolled into view.  This used to work, but it has mysteriously stopped.  I have searched for a setting using words like "breakpoint", "debug", and "scroll" but have had no luck.

This seems to be happening only for my golang project, as the expected breakpoint behavior happens in a python project.  I am running VS Code Go Extension v0.37.1, VS Code version 1.75.1.

Comment: smells like regresion, but [the debug adapter source code](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/src/debugAdapter/goDebug.ts) hasn't changed since Nov 23, 2022 and [v0.37.1 was released Jan 17, 2023](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.37.1), so I have no idea. Maybe there's a bug in VS Code instead of the go extension? I presume you are on VS Code 1.75.1?

Comment: Yes, version 1.75.1.  Description updated.

Comment: This also stopped working for me, in my case in both JS and Python, some months ago.